# unable to click on ribbon button in Dynamics CRM selenium java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to click on a ribbon button on Dynamics crm but It cant see it in any way

> Result : no such element

this is my code (java-selenium ) for this element:

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button")));
act.click();
act.build().perform();
```

and this is my html

> [image: view code from image]

Comment: Hi! What happens if you open Chrome Console (F12) and enter `"$$("#jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button")"` in console? Does it return the element?
Also, take a look at drop-down in the console. There are values like `top` and iframes. If console happens to find the element in the console, it will automatically change the view to desired `iframe`

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Comment: Try this one: `$$("*[id='jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button']");`

Comment: I cant find values of top and iframes. am not sure if its a frame issue
in my previous page I can click on buttons of same type( ribbon buttons), but as I click next to the next page , my submit button appears next to these buttons above the form (ribbon buttons) once its added to them I cant click on any of them.

Comment: in top , I have two things before the frame, which doesn't focus on any thg, and for the frame it doesn't come over my buttons. it comes above the form which is bellow my buttons.

Comment: If the console doesn't return the element then it does not exist. What's below the `<li>` tag you're trying to click? What child elements?

Comment: how can I use "command" attribute to execute it in console?

Comment: `$$` is the command to run cssSelector. Is this what you ask for?

Comment: this is what I mean :
command="jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Submit.Command" 

I tried to put it in $$ ,  I wonder if it should do action , not only show values

Comment: No, this value is probably parsed and sent to backend. You shouldn't be able to run this command from the browser because it's not browser-related command

Answer (score 0):

when you are dealing with the  you first need to switch to them before actual finding out elements.

you can find element by using xpath also,

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//li[contains(@id,'jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button')]"))
```

so, try switching your required iframe using,

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button")));
```

Then try to find that element

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("jwl_bi_newcustomer|NoRelationship|Form|jwl.jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button")));
act.click();
act.build().perform();
```

to come again earlier frame use,

```
 driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: it seems it's not a frame issue , I tried all your suggestion but none of them worked.
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"*//li[contains(@id,'jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button')]"}

Comment: i think its dynamic component so new id gets generated each time

Comment: what do you suggests to do ?

Comment: i mean id is remains same after refreshing the page i.e. 'jwl_bi_newcustomer.Button1.Button' OR check that <li> tag is clickable or not.   
Usually we clicks on <button> tag mostly.    
You need to find element correctly before.click() on it.  
I can see there are lots of stucture tags inside <li> tag.

Comment: it remains the same. eclipse cant read the id of the button because it can't find it so defiantly I can't click on it. I tried to use title to get to it but also it didn't work.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//li[@command= 'PUT_YOUR_COMMAND_VALUE_HERE' ]")); or driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//li[contains(@command, 'PUT_YOUR_COMMAND_VALUE_HERE' )]"))

Comment: you can use command attribute by provideing xpath Already rplied to you still asking,    driver.findElement(By.XPath("*//li[@command= 'jwl_bi_newcustomer' ]"));

Comment: sorry I didn't see your answer, though it didn't work , still I have no such element exception.

Comment: selenium can detect those elements which are visible to users, not just presence in html code means those are detectable by selenium.  As selenium is user driven so, think you can see that element on screen. rather try to click to trigger them visible on browser window.